# How to insert value at start of column in csv file using shell script

Tags: shell, csv, gcloud

I have the following code to get API data and store it in a csv file:

```
for projectid in `gcloud scc assets list <someorgID>
   --filter="security_center_properties.resource_type=\"google.cloud.resourcemanager.Project\""
   -- format="get(asset["securityCenterProperties"]["resourceDisplayName"])"`
   
   do
       gcloud recommender recommendations list \
       --location=global \
       --recommender=google.iam.policy.Recommender \
       --project=$projectid \
       --format="csv[no-heading](content["overview"], content["operationGroups"])" >> temp_iam.csv  done
```

This will get result such as:

```
cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com,    remove
cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com,    add
```

I want to add the value of $projectid to the first place as:

```
projectid1, cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com, remove
projectid2, cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com, add
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask `awk` to insert the loop variable; here's a simplified loop to demonstrate:

```sh
for projectid in projectid1 projectid2
do
  gcloud ... | awk -v project="$projectid" '{ $1=project ", " $1; print;}'
done
```

This pipes the output of `gcloud ...` to awk; awk is given a variable named "project" which is set to the value of the loop variable `$projectid`. Then on each line of awk's input (gcloud's output), we replace the first field with a concatenation of that `project` variable, a command and a space, then value of the first field -- essentially prefixing the projectid value as the new first value of the CSV output.

The new script would be:

```sh
for projectid in `gcloud scc assets list <someorgID>
   --filter="security_center_properties.resource_type=\"google.cloud.resourcemanager.Project\""
   -- format="get(asset["securityCenterProperties"]["resourceDisplayName"])"`
   do
       gcloud recommender recommendations list \
       --location=global \
       --recommender=google.iam.policy.Recommender \
       --project=$projectid \
       --format="csv[no-heading](content["overview"], content["operationGroups"])" | \
       awk -v project="$projectid" '{ $1=project ", " $1; print;}' >> temp_iam.csv
   done
```

Answer (score 1):

GCP APIs contain the [resource name](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names) in the response, so part of that response contains the project number.

Specifically, `gcloud recommender recommendations list` is calling the `projects.locations.recommenders.recommendations.list` method of the [Recommender API](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/reference/rest), which responds with a [Recommendation resource](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.recommenders.recommendations#resource:-recommendation), and this is received by the `gcloud` tool, which means we already have the project in the response.

To know how to properly print that information, we can look at [`gcloud topic projections`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections), and we can see a few transforms that could be applicable here.

If you're interested in the project number, you can select the second segment (index 1) of the name resource for the recommendation:

```
gcloud recommender recommendations list --format="value(name.segment(1))" --location=global --recommender=google.iam.policy.Recommender
```

To include this in your current command that prints a CSV, you can use:

```
gcloud recommender recommendations list \
  --location=global \
  --recommender=google.iam.policy.Recommender \
  --project=$projectid \
  --format="csv[no-heading](name.segment(1),content["overview"], content["operationGroups"])" >> temp_iam.csv
```